# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter' after installing python3-tk an also pip3 update an install tk

Tags: python

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMVyp.png)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
[sudo] password for lts: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  blt libtk8.6 tk8.6-blt2.5
Suggested packages:
  blt-demo tk8.6 tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  blt libtk8.6 python3-tk tk8.6-blt2.5
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,523 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,968 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 libtk8.6 amd64 8.6.13-2 [776 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 tk8.6-blt2.5 amd64 2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2 [643 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 blt amd64 2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2 [4,838 B]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 python3-tk amd64 3.11.2-2 [100 kB]
Fetched 1,523 kB in 1s (1,828 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libtk8.6:amd64.
(Reading database ... 152816 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtk8.6_8.6.13-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtk8.6:amd64 (8.6.13-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.6-blt2.5.
Preparing to unpack .../tk8.6-blt2.5_2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tk8.6-blt2.5 (2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package blt.
Preparing to unpack .../blt_2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking blt (2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-tk:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-tk_3.11.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk:amd64 (3.11.2-2) ...
Setting up libtk8.6:amd64 (8.6.13-2) ...
Setting up tk8.6-blt2.5 (2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2) ...
Setting up blt (2.5.3+dfsg-4.1build2) ...
Setting up python3-tk:amd64 (3.11.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.37-0ubuntu2) ...
```

debug used to work with visual studio code after installing all the right files

```
pip install tk
Requirement already satisfied: tk in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.0)
```

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O79cV.png)

Comment: Why are you using duplicate `import tkinter`?

Comment: missed coded I delete the unused import still have the same issue

Comment: Am on Visual Studio Code Running on Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: How do you execute the script?

Comment: using F5 or just pressing the debugger icon... I have Python 3.11.2

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install python3-tk`

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), and [code formatting help](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

`python3-tk` is being installed for Python 3.11 (based on its version number 3.11.2-2), but VSCode is using Python 3.10. You can see that in the bottom right of your screenshots as well as the `pip` output. You can either:

- [Switch the Python interpreter VSCode is using](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)
- Install Tkinter in your Python 3.10 environment

  How to do that depends on your Python 3.10 setup. You might be able to use APT:

  ```
  sudo apt install python3.10-tk
  ```

---

Secondly, [PyPI's `tk` package](https://pypi.org/project/tk/) is not Tkinter, it's "TensorKit". I don't think Tkinter is even on PyPI since it's in the standard library.